# What's the word that means the opposite of the phrase rock bottom?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

Another phrase that means the opposite of it isn't really what I'm looking for but anything is better then nothing.

Answer (score 3):

**pinnacle** (*noun*):

the most successful point; the [culmination](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/culmination#culmination__2)

> '*He had reached the pinnacle of his career.*'

Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)

Answer (score 2):

At the zenith? At the apogee? On top of the world?

Comment: Finacially or career-wise: At the ...apex? acme? peak? summit? . . . . . On cloud nine? In the lap of luxury? |||||| or, Psychologically: Blissful / Blissed out? Elated? Never felt better?  On top of the world?

Answer (score 1):

For a nice parallel, I would suggest "sky-high".

Answer (score 0):

**plateau** –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=plateau&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

> 1. reach a state of little or no change after a time of activity or progress. *"the industry's problems have plateaued out"*

Since the opposite isn't really what you're looking for, *state of no change*, seems appropriate. One hopes to never plateau at rock bottom.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the words provided by others, consider *[prime](http://i.word.com/idictionary/prime)* (i.e., "the period in life when a person is best in health, strength, etc.").

For example, "After realizing he was no longer in his prime, Doug the Celebrity descended the slippery slope of substance abuse until he hit rock-bottom."